# How to save output from tf.random.normal()

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, operating-system

```
random_vector = tf.random.normal(shape = (25, latent_dim,)
```

I am training my model with the above random vector and saving the outputs as a gird of 5x5.jpg file. But since my dataset has 60k images I am unable to find the corresponding input images.
My question is how can I save the random_vector as a 5x5 grid. Here is the code I used to save output from my model:

```
def save_images(model, epoch, step, input_):
prediction = model.predict(input_)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(5,5, figsize = (14,14))
idx = 0
for row in range(5):
    for column in range(5):
        image = prediction[idx] * 255
        image = image.astype("int32")
        axes[row, column].imshow(image)
        axes[row, column].axis("off")
        idx+=1
output_path = "./anime-faces/"
if not os.path.exists(output_path):
    os.mkdir(output_path)
plt.savefig(output_path + "Epoch_{:04d}_step_{:04d}.jpg".format(epoch, step))
plt.close()
```

I am new to tensorflow and AIML so most of the code is written from different sources on internet, sorry if it is something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a similar code that you are using for saving the output images, on the `input_` that you feed into the function `save_images`, giving

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(5,5, figsize = (latent_dim,))
idx = 0
for row in range(5):
    for column in range(5):
        image = inputs_[idx] * 255
        image = image.astype("int32")
        axes[row, column].imshow(image)
        axes[row, column].axis("off")
        idx+=1
output_path = "./anime-faces-inputs/"
if not os.path.exists(output_path):
    os.mkdir(output_path)
plt.savefig(output_path + ".jpg")
plt.close()
```

Comment: Hi, I tried what you suggested, First error that i got is from_bounds() missing 1 required positional argument: 'height', suggesting that figsize is missing height attribute, after changing that to 14,14 i get this error:
'EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'astype'.
        If you are looking for numpy-related methods, please run the following:
        from tensorflow.python.ops.numpy_ops import np_config
        np_config.enable_numpy_behavior()

Comment: Then maybe try to convert the tf tensor to a numpy array using `image = np.array(inputs_[idx]*255)`

Comment: Invalid shape (512,) for image data. This is what I get